# Dynamic Re-size a Canvas box to match an image box

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I must create an application that requires me to have an image inside of an image box and I must draw on top of the image in a canvas box that is to be placed directly on top. I can't place the image inside the canvas box as I need the image to stay it's original size. Is it possible to have the canvas box match the image box as it changes sizes and move to the proper place directly on top of the image box?

Comment: A `Canvas` does not adjust the size of it's children like many other WPF panels do, so you are safe to place the `ImageBox` inside of the `Canvas`, and it will keep it's original size.

Comment: Glad that worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rachel put it: "A Canvas does not adjust the size of it's children like many other WPF panels do, so you are safe to place the ImageBox inside of the Canvas, and it will keep it's original size."